# Why for loop only shows result of last loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I have this sample matrix:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  F  F  F  F
2  C  C  C  C
3  D  D  D  D
4 A# A# A#  A
```

And I'm trying to use a for loop to get the number of unique pitches in each column. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
y <- read.csv(file)
frame <- data.frame(y)
for(i in 1:4){
specframe <- frame[, i]
x <- unique(specframe)
         }
     length(x)
```

But the result of length is just 4. The output I'm looking for is a vector of 4 elements in which each element details the number of unique elements in their respective columns. It looks like the for loop is rewriting x every time it loops, so how would I make a vector which contains an element for each time it loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

```
y <- read.csv(file)
x <- numeric(4)
for(i in 1:4) {
    x[i] <- length(unique(y[, i]))
}
```

or:

```
x <- apply(y,2,function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Comment: I tried implementing your first solution, but it gave the correct answer for the last loop four times. To test that, I changed the fourth column to have a fifth unique value. Then, when I run your first solution, I get: [1] 5 5 5 5, even though the first three columns only have 4 values.

Comment: Wait, I think I figured out the issue: When I run the code for only the first three columns, which all have a blank space for the last row, they still return [1] 5 5 5. So I think the blank space is considered a unique value. Is there a way to prevent the unique() function from considering the space? I tried using the na.strings argument in the read.csv function, but unique() still considers the NA to be a unique value.

Comment: If you want a detailed answer you need to show the results of running `dput()` on your input data set ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `n_distinct` (wrapper for `length(unique(`) from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   summarise_each(funs(n_distinct)) %>%
   unlist()
```