# Reading through all excel file sheets and performing a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to read into all the sheets in an excel file and sum columns X__9 and X__11. My foor loop only returns said operation for only one sheet and I'm not sure how to solve this.

```
library(readxl)
sheets <- excel_sheets("C:/Users/Victor/Downloads/transacties-3.xlsx")
path <- "C:/Users/Victor/Downloads/transacties-3.xlsx"

for(i in sheets){
  result <-  data.frame()
  data <- read_excel(path,sheet=i)
  data <- data[10:12]
  data$X__9 <- as.numeric(data$X__9)
  data$X__11 <- as.numeric(data$X__11)
  result <- rbind(result,data.frame(data))
  sum <- apply(result,1,sum,na.rm=T)
  return(sum)
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584177/why-for-loop-only-shows-result-of-last-loop)

Answer (score 0):

you should define result dataframe outside the loop.

```
result <-  data.frame()
for(i in sheets){
  data <- read_excel(path,sheet=i)
  data <- data[10:12]
  data$X__9 <- as.numeric(data$X__9)
  data$X__11 <- as.numeric(data$X__11)
  result <- rbind(result,data.frame(data))
}

sum1 <- sum(result$X__9)
sum1 <- sum(result$X__11)
```

Comment: Did not work. For some reason after running the code I see in my environment i as value "Table 1". So I believe the loop is not running through all the values in sheets.

Comment: @kevinn-12 i have updated the answer,you don't have to return inside the loop.check the answer

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for. The problem still persists as the loop only iterates over the first sheet.